# Force pushing after line ending changed in setting

Tags: git, git-push

I have changed line ending setting by updating autocrlf after I pushed all my codes.

```
autocrlf = false
```

Now I need to push my local to repository again to over write the files and the LF problem will be resolved.

I tried to push the code using -f

`git push -f`

```
git push origin master -f
```

but none of them is working and get "Everything up-to-date" message.

How can I force git to rewrite all files from my local?

Comment: I don't have time to write a proper answer, but: you are working with an incorrect mental model of how Git actually works. What `git push` pushes is not *files* but rather *commits*. What `core.autocrlf` does is affect the *index* and the *work-tree*, which itself has only an indirect effect on the commits themselves. You might also benefit from explaining in your question what you expect to achieve on the other Git at `remote.origin.url`.

Comment: Perhaps this section in github help page will help you with your problem https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/#refreshing-a-repository-after-changing-line-endings